# Is there a name for gitignore's search pattern

Tags: git, gitignore

`.gitignore` lines have their specific rules of interpretation.

https://linux.die.net/man/5/gitignore

```
â€¢ A blank line matches no files, so it can serve as a separator for readability. 
â€¢ A line starting with # serves as a comment. 
â€¢ An optional prefix ! which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. If a negated pattern matches, this will override lower precedence patterns sources. 
â€¢ If the pattern ends with a slash, it is removed for the purpose of the following description, but it would only find a match with a directory. In other words, foo/ will match a directory foo and paths underneath it, but will not match a regular file or a symbolic link foo (this is consistent with the way how pathspec works in general in git). 
â€¢ If the pattern does not contain a slash /, git treats it as a shell glob pattern and checks for a match against the pathname without leading directories. 
â€¢ Otherwise, git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption by fnmatch(3) with the FNM_PATHNAME flag: wildcards in the pattern will not match a / in the pathname. For example, "Documentation/*.html" matches "Documentation/git.html" but not "Documentation/ppc/ppc.html". A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname; for example, "/*.c" matches "cat-file.c" but not "mozilla-sha1/sha1.c".
```

The same rules are used by other tools as well, e.g. the `files` key in npm's `package.json` expects the same format.

Is there a name for this pattern? Or what would be the most suitable name?

Answer (score 2):

Another formal documentation of these rules are in the [`git-scm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) docs.

I think the closest thing that `.gitignore` resembles is [`glob` pattern matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) which they mention in some of the documentation:

> If the pattern does not contain a slash /, git treats it as a **shell glob pattern** and checks for a match against the pathname without leading directories.

However, it isn't exactly the same which is why they specify the rules.